# Validating that all strings in an array match a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to validate a list of objects for example strings. and if one of the objects fails to pass the condition return false as validation result . this is the code I use :

```
    public static bool AreValid(string[] strs)
    {
        foreach (string str in strs)
        {
            if (str != condition )
            {
                return false; // does this breaks the for loop ?
                // break;     // no need to this
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

is this a correct approach ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, `return` immediately* returns from the method, no matter where in the method you are. You don't need the `break`.

But there is even easier way to write this code, using the LINQ method [`All()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
strs.All(str => str == condition)
```

This also returns as soon as single non-matching element is found and is more readable.

---

* Actually, `finally` blocks run before you actually return from the method, but that's not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Any would be a bit faster than All

```
return !strs.Any(str => str != condition);
```

Comment: [Enumerable.All](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,be4bfd025bd2724c) returns as soon as the condition does not match. Therefore there is no difference in performance but Enumerable.All is more readable.

Comment: Hmm.. in that case both will have similar performance